# how can i override font color for anchor tag of dropdow-menu in navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am try changing anchor tag font color of dropdown-menu but i am not able to override it.

```
navbar
 <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top no-margin">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#/" class="navbar-brand navleftfont">Professional</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right">
                    <li><a class="navrightfont" href="#/abc/home">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle navrightfont">Information<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul  class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#/abc/login">login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/abc/search">search</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="navrightfont navrightfont" href="#">contact</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

css to over ride font color for anchor tag text inside dropdown-menu of list.

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: white; 
    background:white;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

i have tried also like but not working. i almost tried all solution suggested on post but no luck.

```
.navbar a{
color:white}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a{
    color: white; 
}
```

please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try being more specific in your css:

```
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

if that doesnt work try overriding with !important

```
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried you code  ...and it works for me 
may be you should add bootstrap befour your css  ..for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
```

thene you css here ..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">
```

because bootstrap may override your style